# Font Enumeration Java

Tags: java, enums

I am fairly new to Java, but learning it pretty quickly. Currently a program I am creating which writes a document to PDF uses a large variety of Fonts. I would like to declare these as an enumeration (they are currently in a class file named Fonts and declared as public static final which works fine) but I cant seem to work out how to declare what Font each particular enumeration is equal to even after reading several pieces of documentation regarding enumerations. I know enumeration is the more sensible approach so would prefer to implement this if possible.

Just after some guidance really.

My font class file is as follows.

```
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.CMYKColor;

public class Fonts {

public static final Font REG16 = new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 16));
public static final Font REG13 = new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 13));
public static final Font BOLD13 = new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 13, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK));
public static final Font BOLD11 = new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 11, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK));
public static final Font BOLD10 = new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK));
public static final Font GREY11 = new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 11, BaseColor.GRAY));
public static final Font GREYBOLD10 = new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 10, Font.BOLDITALIC, BaseColor.GRAY));
public static final Font REG10 = new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 10));
public static final Font REG11 = new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 11));
public static final Font GREYBOLD17 =  new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 17, Font.BOLDITALIC));
public static final Font WHITEBOLD38 =  new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 38, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE));
public static final Font WHITEBOLD20 = new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 20, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE));
public static final Font WHITEBOLD10 = new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE));                    // Declare fonts.
public static final Font BOLDITALIC11 =  new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 11, Font.BOLDITALIC, BaseColor.BLACK));
public static final Font ORANGEBOLD12 = new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 12, Font.BOLDITALIC, new CMYKColor(0, 0.2f, 1f, 0)));
}
```

Comment: Hardcoded path...not really portable.

Answer (score 2):

You could create an `enum` with a `Font` property for each instance.

Something in the lines of:

```
enum Fonts {

    REG16(new Font(FontFactory.getFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Calibri.ttf", 16))),
    ...
    ;

    private Font f;

    Fonts(Font f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    public Font getFont() {
        return this.f;
    }
}
```